# Find the encoding method of a string

Tags: python, hex, decode, encode

I am working with an xml file where numbers are encoded with different methods.
Headline says "xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"" , but I found not only utf8 is used.
The following strings I believe that the same encoding method are used. But I cant figure out the method that is used.  Please see below strings are corresponding decimals and units in brackets.  the string may or may not include the units.

```
40413CA4FCA42AED  5.000 (ksi)
40A2C00000000000  0.15 (kcf)  
40A2200000000000  0.145 (kcf)
40DB627A7915AB7E  4067.135889 (ksi)
3FC999999999999A  0.2 (no unit)
400D99D5D4C224D1  0.5366563 (ksi)
```

below is the python code I made to interpret these strings.  out of the 6 strings, I got one right which is the 0.2

```
import struct
# define double_to_hex (or float_to_hex)
def double_to_hex(f):
    return hex(struct.unpack('<Q', struct.pack('<d', f))[0])
print(double_to_hex(0.5366563))
```

any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I'd guess at unit mismatch.

```
import struct
import pandas as pd
import io   

mydata = '''hxstr decval unit
40413CA4FCA42AED 5.000 (ksi)
40A2C00000000000 0.15 (kcf)
40A2200000000000 0.145 (kcf)
40DB627A7915AB7E 4067.135889 (ksi)
3FC999999999999A 0.2 (nou)
400D99D5D4C224D1 0.5366563 (ksi)
'''

df = pd.read_csv( io.StringIO(mydata), sep=" ")
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    print( 
      row.hxstr,
      row.unit,
      struct.unpack(
        '>d',
        bytes.fromhex(row.hxstr))[0] / float(row.decval))
```

**Result** shows roughly the same ratio for the same units:

```
40413CA4FCA42AED (ksi) 6.894757
40A2C00000000000 (kcf) 16000.0
40A2200000000000 (kcf) 16000.000000000002
40DB627A7915AB7E (ksi) 6.89475699994749
3FC999999999999A (nou) 1.0
400D99D5D4C224D1 (ksi) 6.894757187574625
```

Here

- `6.894757` ratio for *ksi* resembles the following conversion (providing that ***ksi*** means *kilopound per square inch*): [1 ksi = 6.8947572932 MPa (Megapascal)](https://www.unitconverters.net/pressure/ksi-to-megapascal.htm),
- `1.0` ratio for *no unit* seems to be correct, however
- `16000.0` ratio for *kcf* I can't identify…